# Error extracting audio from video(in raw folder) in android. Error: no such file or directory

Tags: android, android-studio, audio

I would like to elaborate on my question. What I actually want to do is that I have a video in the raw folder of my android resource directory. Now I want to extract audio from that video on a button click. Now I want to directly extract audio from that video, instead of first having to save that video to my device.
This is the code I tried to accomplish this.

```
Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "/raw/sample3");
//File file = new File(video.toString());
String str = video.toString();
//File file = new File(video.toString());
Log.d("new", "onClick: " + str);
//Log.d("new", "onClick: "+file);

//InputStream stream = context.getResources().openRawResource( R.raw.sample3 );
//String string = stream.toString();

File moviesDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC);

String filePrefix = "extract_audio";
String fileExtn = ".mp3";
//String yourRealPath = getPath(context, selectedVideoUri);_
File dest = new File(moviesDir, filePrefix + fileExtn);

int fileNo = 0;
while (dest.exists())
{
    fileNo++;
    dest = new File(moviesDir, filePrefix + fileNo + fileExtn);
}
Log.d("str", "startTrim: src: " + video);
Log.d("str", "startTrim: dest: " + dest.getAbsolutePath());
filePath = dest.getAbsolutePath();
try
{
    new AudioExtractor().genVideoUsingMuxer(str, filePath, -1, -1, true, false);
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And this is the error I am getting.
Failed to open file 'android.content.res.AssetManager$AssetInputStream@5510500'. (No such file or directory)

Please guide me through this. What mistake I am making and what I am ignoring? This is the remaining logcat:

```
 2020-07-25 17:48:28.254 21653-21653/com.cgfay.caincamera E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.cgfay.caincamera, PID: 21653
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(MediaMetadataRetriever.java:76)
    at com.cgfay.caincamera.utils.AudioExtractor.genVideoUsingMuxer(AudioExtractor.java:72)
    at com.cgfay.caincamera.adapters.HomeAdapter$1.onClick(HomeAdapter.java:140)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6608)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6585)
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:785)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25921)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

This is the `genVideoUsingMuxer()` method.

```
public void genVideoUsingMuxer(String srcPath, String dstPath, int startMs, int endMs, 
        boolean useAudio, boolean useVideo)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now i want to extract audio from that video on a button click

It would be simpler and more efficient for you to do this on your development machine and put the extracted audio in your app. The extracted audio will be the same for all users, since the video is the same for all users.

> Now i want to directly extract audio from that video, instead of first having to save that video to my device

You would need to find some library that can do that, while using an `InputStream` as the source of the video. Then, you would be able to use `Resources` and `openRawResource()` get an `InputStream` on your resource and pass that to the library.

> Please guide me through this. what mistake i am making and what im ignoring

You appear to be assuming that a `Uri` is a filesystem path (it is not) and that a resource is a file on the device (it is not).

Comment: so this is why it was showing no such file or directory error? Because the raw file was in my project but does not exist on my phone?

Comment: @syedkhizrali: Correct.